# Swift: How to determine position on screen the user is looking at in Swift without ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, eye-tracking

I am currently trying to estimate the position on the screen where the user is looking at. The goal is to trigger an action when the user blinks with his eyes. E.g. there is a button on the screen and instead of touching it, the user should look at the button and blink in order trigger the action. Is there any way this is possible without ARKit, as ARKit front camera depth is only available for iPhone X.

Thanks in advance